# i have created this table from database.Now if anyone updates the value in table how can it be reflected back in database?

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a simple page to test a database connection. When I tried accessing it from my browser, it says:

> Server error
>
> The website encountered an error while retrieving `http://localhost:8888/blah/blah/test.php`. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
>
> Here are some suggestions:
>
> Reload this webpage later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

All I am doing is connecting to a database and displaying the tables. Here is what I have so far as the PHP code:

```
<?php
// Get Variables
$dbname = $_GET["dbname"];
$dbusername = $_GET["dbusername"];
$dbpass = $_GET["dbpass"];
$dbhost = $_GET["dbhost"];






$connection = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpass");
if (!$connection)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Connected";

    $dbcheck = mysql_select_db("$dbname");
    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }else{
        echo "<p>Successfully connected to the database '" . $database . "'</p>\n";
// Check tables
        $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM `$database`";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "<p>Available tables:</p>\n";
            echo "<pre>\n";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                echo "{$row[0]}\n";
            }
            echo "</pre>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<p>The database '" . $database . "' contains no tables.</p>\n";
            echo mysql_error();
        }



    }

// some code

    mysql_close($con);



    ?>
```

My error in the WAMP Apache logs is:

```
[03-Feb-2013 22:47:37 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file                              in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/coursemanager/default/verify1.php on line 52
```

What would a unexpected end of file be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

It means you forgot to close the last }

```
<?php
// Get Variables
$dbname = $_GET["dbname"];
$dbusername = $_GET["dbusername"];
$dbpass = $_GET["dbpass"];
$dbhost = $_GET["dbhost"];

$connection = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpass");
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Connected";

    $dbcheck = mysql_select_db("$dbname");
    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    } else {
        echo "<p>Successfully connected to the database '" . $database . "'</p>\n";
        // Check tables
        $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM `$database`";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "<p>Available tables:</p>\n";
            echo "<pre>\n";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                echo "{$row[0]}\n";
            }
            echo "</pre>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<p>The database '" . $database . "' contains no tables.</p>\n";
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    }
    // some code
    mysql_close($con);
}
```